# Existence of a singleton set (AC for a singleton set)

Tags: set-theory

If $x$ is a nonempty set, is it in general possible to prove from ZF that there exists a singleton set the only element of which is in $x$ ?

This would be the result of applying the axiom of choice to the set $\{ x\}$.
Something like this is needed in the proof that if there exists an injective function $f:x\to y$, there exists a surjective function $g:y\to x$. I have been told that this proof requires the axiom of choice, however I find that a bit strange since all you need to do is set $g(z)=f^{-1}(z)$ if $f^{-1}(z)$ exists and $g(z)=v$ for a fixed $v\in x$ otherwise. Such a function $g$ is clearly surjective, but to prove its existence one needs the existence of a set of the above mentioned kind (or a function which picks one element from x).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use replacement to generate from $x$ the set of $\{\{v\}\mid v\in x\}$. This is set is not empty because $x$ is not empty, then its elements are the required singletons.

Choosing from a single set does not require the axiom of choice, so you may choose $\{v\}$ from it.

Lastly you don't need the axiom of choice to prove there is a surjective inverse for injections (from nonempty sets). You need the axiom of choice to prove that there is an injective inverse to a surjection, indeed this is an equivalent formulation of the axiom of choice.

Comment: Replacement seems like a big gun for this simple thing. Couldn't we pick $y \in x$ and apply pairing to $y$ only?

Comment: @Lord_Farin: You could also use power set and subset schema. And you can also do that thing. But replacement is one of the best tools of ZF, I'd hate to see it left in the corner accumulating dust.

Comment: True. But sometimes one wants to investigate $\mathsf Z$, which omits Replacement. It could be useful to know that the construction does not _depend_ on Replacement. Other than that, I agree that it is one of the most useful axioms, the existence of $2\omega$ resting on it makes this quite clear.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Yes, with that I agree. However your answer included such a solution (and I wanted to be original), later to be incorporated by Arthur in his answer. I should point out that I doubt in the history of mathematics someone was consciously able to choose $\sf Z$ over $\sf ZF$ and did not know that to choose a singleton subset requires very little.

Answer (score 6):

Since $x \neq \emptyset$ there is a $y \in x$.  By Pairing there is a set $\{ y , y \} = \{ y \}$.

In general, making **finitely** many *choices* can be done in ZF in basically the same manner:

> Suppose pairwise disjoint nonempty sets $x_1 , x_2 , \ldots , x_n$ are given.  Since $x_1 \neq \emptyset$ there is a $y_1 \in x_1$.  Since $x_2 \neq \emptyset$ there is a $y_2 \in x_2$.  .... Since $x_n \neq \emptyset$ there is a $y_n \in x_n$.  Now by applications of Pairing and Union the set $\{ y_1 , y_2 , \ldots , y_n \}$ exists, and is a choice set (transversal) for $x_1 , \ldots , x_n$.

Comment: No, you read the question wrong. I don't want the existence of $\{x\}$, but of a $\{v\}$ for $v\in x$.

Comment: @user35359: <redface>